# SQLite Exception: Insert statement does not return a Statement

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLiteJDBC as the wrapper for an embedded database for my small Java app. Everytime I execute an INSERT statement, I get the following exception:

**query does not return ResultSet**

I am wondering if the JDBC Statement.executeStatement(String) method is looking for me to return a ResultSet, but that the SQLite driver knows that INSERT statements don't return anything; maybe SQLiteJDBC is throwing an error because it shouldn't be returning the ResultSet that Statement is asking for?!?

Here is the code that is producing the exception - I have made sure to setup and close all resources properly:

```
statement = con.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO widgets (widget_age) VALUES (27)";
statement.executeStatement(sql);
```

Any ideas?!?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you are making a change and not asking for a result back, you need to call [`executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `executeStatement()`.

EDIT

I can't even find a reference to `executeStatement()` anywhere.  Were you using `executeQuery()`?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite always returns a message quen you execute a Query.

It's normal to have that warning/error, it's simply that no rows where returned so you can't use them in the callback if you defined one.

PD: I also think you meant executeQuery